# Training stuck at certain loss

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, errors-in-training

I am new to NN and particularly to TensorFlow.

I have implemented a simple network with 1 hidden layer and the loss output as below in the figure. I have read many blog posts, and forums to figure out the solution to my problem. I cannot figure out why my training get stuck and do not get below a certain % error.

[image]

I don't want a final answer, but a direction into which I should look at. Note that the above graph is for the data generated that I generated to test what is wrong with my system. The figure below is the actual output from the real-world values for which I want to train my system.

[image]

Following is my code if someone is interested:

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_predicted, logits=output_logits), name='loss')
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, name='Adam-op').minimize(loss)

```
correct_prediction = tf.equal(output_logits, y_predicted, name='correct_pred')
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name='accuracy')

# Create the op for initializing all variables
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Create an interactive session (to keep the session in the other cells)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Initialize all variables
sess.run(init)

feed_dict_data = {x_input: x_train, y_predicted: y_train}
loss_var = []
acc_var = []
# Batch Gradient Descent
num_tr_iter = 10000
for iteration in range(num_tr_iter):

    # Run optimization op (backprop)
    sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_data)
    loss_var.append(sess.run(loss, feed_dict = feed_dict_data))
```

Comment: Have you tried different learning rates?

Comment: Yes, I have tried multiple learning rates. There is no much difference.

Comment: What other model architectures have you tried?

Comment: I have tried NN with a single hidden layer (and of course an output layer) and NN with multiple hidden layers. I tried different learning rates, and have tried different number of neurons per layer (of course changing one parameter at a time)